# May Promise.all().finally() return unresolved data?

Tags: node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I found quite unusual behavior of Promise.all().finally() - look like it returning data before map() was applied to this.
 1. Data received from database.
 2. Making call to Google Maps API inside map(), applied to the data retrieved from database and adding to the object property "Distance" with result from Google API call.
 3. Return data in Promise.all() - data received without new property.
I can't get how this even possible?

```
public static get = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const latitude = req.query.lat;
    const longitude = req.query.long;
    const pool = await new sql.ConnectionPool(CommonConstants.connectionString).connect();
    const request = pool.request();
    const result = await request.execute('SuppliersSP');
    sql.close();
    const rows = result.recordset.map(async (supplier) => {
        const data = { origin: [latitude, longitude], destination: [supplier.Latitude, supplier.Longitude] };
        const distance = await GetDistance(data) || 0;
        Object.defineProperty(supplier, 'Distance', {
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: distance
          });
        return supplier;
    })
    Promise.all(rows).finally(() => {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.status(200).json(rows);
    });
}
```

Here is GetDistance function:

```
import { Constants } from "./constants";
const https = require('https');

    export function GetDistance(coords) {
        const { origin, destination } = coords;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            https.get(`${Constants.GoogleMapsUrl}?origins=${origin[0]},${origin[1]}
             &destinations=${destination[0]},${destination[1]}
             &key=${Constants.GoogleMapsApiKey}`, (resp) => {
                let data = '';
                resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    data += chunk;
                });
                resp.on('end', () => {
                    const distance = JSON.parse(data);
                    resolve(distance.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value);
                });
            }).on("error", (err) => {
                reject("Error: " + err.message);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is `recordset` an array of Promises?

Comment: `map` doesn't map in-place.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, not exactly, one of the object properties are Promise.

Comment: @tkausl, what do you mean?

Comment: Then `Promise.all(result.recordset)` doesn't make sense - only use `Promise.all` on an array of Promises

Comment: @andrey.shedko `result.recordset` doesn't change, you need to call `Promise.all` on the return value of `result.recordset.map()`

Comment: @tkausl, yes, you're right, but now `rows` are array of promises that should be resolved by `Promise.all()` although it;s not.

Comment: It solved by changing `.finally()` to `.then()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was solved by a change `.finally()` to `.then()`.